# FixedDocument as a reporting engine?

Tags: c#, wpf, reporting

I'm wondering about using WPF's `FixedDocument` as a reporting engine. Does anyone have such experience? What are possible pitfalls?

An application I'm developing now, must print some reports. These are orders, invoices - that is, there is nothing unusual. Recently, I've looked at `FlowDocument` and `FixedDocumet` concepts, and I've found, that `FixedDocumet` is, theoretically, what I need.

Than, I've sketched a sample report, and faced with a problem:

```
    <PageContent>
        <FixedPage Width="793.76" Height="1122.56" Margin="50,50,50,50" PrintTicket="">
            <ListView Width="Auto" Height="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="First name" 
                                        Width="200"
                                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Last name" 
                                        Width="200"
                                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}"/>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
        </FixedPage>
    </PageContent>
```

[image: Footer of fixed document]

There is a common practice in reporting to split long table-kind data into multiple pages (e.g., invoice with 1000 items). Also, it is usual for user to have an option, to repeat a table header on each page, or not to repeat.

Is there any out-of-box way to do this with `FixedPage`/`ItemsControl`?
If no, how to define at run-time, that current item to be rendered is out of page? So long as fixed page is a just a set of UIElements, I can generate them dynamically.

P.S. I know about different commercial reporting engines, the questions isn't about them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My experience has shown that FixedDocument is completely useless when it comes to printing/custom solutions.

First of all, it even doesn't support printing to multiple pages by default. You  need to have custom DocumentPaginator for that functionality.

My two cents is that, don't use it. Go with ReportViewer. Much flexibility.

It's well possible to do everything with FixedDocument but the cost/time is not worth it. It's almost same as comparing ASM and high level language. yes, you can do everything in ASM but it's not worth it.

FixedDocument can't be really called reporting engine, since it doesn't have any "engine-like" functionality.